# Chrome Device Simulator like app to show different breakpoints in React/Next/Tailwind app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, simulator

I was working on a website builder app where i want to Simulate devices with Device Mode same exactly like Chrome.
Is there any component library for that or any npm package or anything.

I tried creating it by my own, but here i have to put all the devices manually and also cannot resize the window (divwrapper) in case and also by setting the width manually It's not reflecting the responsiveness inside the wrapper div.

I'm open up to anu suggestions.

Thank you :)

I tried creating it by my own, but here i have to put all the devices manually and also cannot resize the window (divwrapper) in case and also by setting the width manually It's not reflecting the responsiveness inside the wrapper div.